# ImportError: No module named tkinter. Mac OS Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, module, terminal

I have created a Tkinter window in a python script. The script runs perfectly in the python IDLE and generates the GUI. However, when I run this file outside of the IDLE by clicking on it on my Desktop, the terminal responds with ImportError: No module named tkinter. Even though tkinter is installed as its a default module when python is installed. Any help is much appreciated. Im working on python 3.7

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your default python , the one that the terminal calls has tkinter installed.

So run `'python --version'` in the terminal and if that yields 3.7 then your default python is 3.7.

Now try to import tkinter using that same python version.

open the terminal and run `python` then run `import tkinter as tk`

If that does not yield an error saying that the module was not found then most probably you are running the executable with the wrong permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out it was actually python 2 it was calling. Do you know how to change it from the 2.7 to 3.7?

Comment: I have followed the instructions on that link, and it has now set the version to 3.7. But when I click on the py file to run it, it still comes up with the same tkinter error

Comment: Have you tried installing tkinter in python 2 as well?!